# Use separate server for centralized users database

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, sockets, meteor

I am using Meteor 1.10 + mongodb.

I have multiple mobile chat & information applications.

These mobile application are natively developed using Meteor DDP libraries.

But I have same users base for all the apps.

Now I want to create a separate meteor instance on separate individual server to keep the users base centralized.

I need suggestions that how can I acheive this architecture with meteor.

Keeping reactivity and performance in mind.

Comment: See brief discussion here https://forums.meteor.com/t/meteor-user-accounts-as-a-micro-service/33069/10

Comment: @mikkel in the article you referring to, i can't see the reactivity brought into light which is a major concern to me

Comment: Yeah, I don't have an answer, just helping your research. It's a common requirement, but I'm not sure if anyone has done it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finally I got a work around. It might not be the perfect way to handle this, but to my knowledge it worked for me so well. But yes I still open for suggestions.

Currently I have 4 connecting applications which are dependent on same users base.

So I decided to build SSO (Centralized Server for managing Users Database)

All 4 connecting applications ping SSO for User-Authentication and getting users related data.

Now those 4 connecting applications are developed using Meteor.

Main challenge here was to make things Reactive/Realtime.
E.g Chat/Messaging, Group Creations, Showing users list & listeners for newly registered users.

So in this scenario users database was on other remote server (SSO), so on connecting application I couldn't just:

```
Meteor.publish("getUsers")
```

So on connecting applications I decided to create a Temporary Collection called:

```
UserReactiveCollection
```

With following structure:

```
UserReactiveCollection.{
    _id: 1,
    userId: '2',
    createdAt: new Date()
}
```

And I published subscription:

```
Meteor.publish("subscribeNewUserSso", function () {

    return UserReactiveCollection.find({});
});
```

So for updating `UserReactiveCollection` I exposed Rest Api's on each connecting application respectively.
Those apis receive data from SSO and updates in `UserReactiveCollection`.

So on SSO side when ever a new user is registered. I ping those Apis (on connecting applications) and send the inserted userId in the payload.

So now those connecting applications receives `onDataChanged` ping from the subscription and gets userId.

Using that userId the connecting applications pings back to SSO and get user details of that specific userId and prepends to the users list.

Thats how I got it all working so for now I am just marking my answer accepted but as I mentioned above that: **"It might not be the perfect way to handle this, but to my knowledge it worked for me so well. But yes I still open for suggestions."**

And special thanks to @Jankapunkt for helping me out.

Answer (score 0):

For a centralized user-base with full reactive functionality you need an Authorization Server which will be used by your apps (= Resource Servers) in order to allow an authenticated/authorized request. This is basically the OAuth2 3-tier workflow.

See:

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749

https://www.oauth.com/

**Login Service**

You will also have to write your own login handler (`Meteor.loginWithMyCustomAuthServer`) in order to avoid `DDP.connect` because you would then have to manage **two userbases** (one for the app itself and one for the Authorization Server) and this will get really messy.

This login handler is then retrieving the user account data after the Oauth2 authorization request has been successful, which will make the Authorization Server's userbase the single point of truth for any of your app that is registered (read on Oauth2 workflow about `clientId` and `secret`).

**Subcribing to users**

The Auth server is the single point of truth where you create, updat or delete your users **there** and on a successfull login your local app will **always** get the latest user data synced from this accounts Auth Server (this is how Meteor does it with `loginWith<Service>` too)

You then subscribe to your users to the app itself without any ddp remote connection. This of course works only if the user data you want to get is actually for online users.

If you want to subscribe for any user (where the data might have not been synced yet) you still need a remote subscription to a publication on the Authorizazion server.

Note, that in order to authenticate users with this remote subscription you need an authenticated DDP request (which is also backed by the packages below).

**Implementation**

Warning - the following is an implementation by myself. This is due to I have faced the same issue and found no other implementation before mine.

There is a full working Accounts server (but constantly work in progress)

https://github.com/leaonline/leaonline-accounts

it uses an [Oauth2 nodejs implementation](https://github.com/thomseddon/node-oauth2-server), which has been wrapped inside a Meteor package:

https://github.com/leaonline/oauth2-server

and the respective login handler has also been created:

https://github.com/leaonline/meteor-accounts-lea

Comment: Well the thing that confuses me a lot is what would be the implementation on Mobile App side, I mean like do I have to use 2 DDP connections of 2 different ports? E.g I have all the users on centralized server and group chats on another server, so in this scenario how will I subscribe users and groups chats reactively on mobile app?

Comment: The first thing I don't get is how can I "subscribe 10 latest registered users without any DDP remote connection". Assuming that users group chat is on SERVER A and users are on SERVER B (the centralized server).

Comment: If you use the above workflow then like you subscribe in any Meteor app for your 10 latest registered users. This of course requires these users to have been logged in so their data is synced to your app from the Auth server

Comment: Ok but what If they are not logged in? They just signed up and logged out, I still need these users to be shown in the list. And on the same time, if a new user registers, I need that user to appear on the top of the list reactively

Comment: They just need to have been logged in once to sync the user account

Comment: Right I will check its implementation, but I still have so many confusions about the work flow. Its getting messy no matter what solution I implement. I wonder how come Google, stackoverflow & facebook handles these sort of cases.

Comment: any improvments on your side or still struggling?

Comment: Thanks for asking back, much appreciated. Actually I got the flow working now.  I implemented hooks on SSO server in a way that it pings other servers via APIs. e.g If new user is added in SSO database, so on creation success I ping all the connected server that this _id user is registered. So when those connected servers receive that call on their server, they request data for that specific _id user and get user details from SSO and append to the list. All this is being handled via subscription on each server. Since the connected servers are also based on meteor.

Comment: would you mind wrapping that up in some code and answer your own question? Might be interesting to know for others as well.

Comment: Sure I will write the answer in detail. Thanks

Comment: Besides that i would like to get some help from you regarding implemening oauth2 on restapis. I have posted an article on Meteor forums:
https://forums.meteor.com/t/meteor-oauth2-0-implementation-for-rest-apis/52593